# WebView not downloading pop-up file

Tags: javascript, java, android

I'm new to Android studio.
So I have been writing some code that helps my job.
When the imgView and Layout clicked the app will go into WebView
On the WebView they will fill the form, after that the web should automatically downloading the .pdf file.
When I Opened it with chrome, chrome will make a new tab/pop up with some link that triggers downloading files.
How this webView could download the pdf file too? because When I opened it on the Web View, the WebView will go back to previous activity.

```
public class biling extends AppCompatActivity {
private WebView webView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_biling);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
            Log.d("permission", "permission denied to WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE - requesting it");
            String[] permissions = {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
            requestPermissions(permissions, 1);
        }
    }


    webView = findViewById(R.id.bilingweb);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView view, String url) {
            if (url.endsWith(".pdf")) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
                // if want to download pdf manually create AsyncTask here
                // and download file
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    webView.loadUrl("https://sse2.pajak.go.id");
    webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                                    String contentDisposition, String mimeType,
                                    long contentLength) {
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(
                    Uri.parse(url));
            request.setMimeType(mimeType);
            String cookies = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
            request.addRequestHeader("cookie", cookies);
            request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent", userAgent);
            request.setDescription("Downloading File...");
            request.setTitle(URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimeType));
            request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(
                    Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, URLUtil.guessFileName(
                            url, contentDisposition, mimeType));
            DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            dm.enqueue(request);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Downloading File", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }});
    webView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    if (!v.hasFocus()){
                        v.requestFocus();
                    }
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }

    });

    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
    webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webSettings.setDisplayZoomControls(true);
    webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webSettings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true);

    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar1);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("e-Biling");
    getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle("Bayar Pajak Online");
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (webView.canGoBack()){webView.goBack();}
    else
    {super.onBackPressed();}
}
```

}

Comment: After filling in web view , what is your goal? And until which step did you implemented?

Comment: After the user fills the inside form after login, the user will receive/download pdf file for their billing statement.

Comment: Anyway the pdf file downloaded from data:application/pdf;base64 type